# moquette users have privilege different than what is written in the access control list

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, moquette

I am using moquette as my MQTT broker.

I specify an access control file in my config as this:

```
acl_file acl.conf
```

and then in the acl.conf file, I added just one user as this:

```
user gravity
topic read in
topic write out
```

#### My problem

The user *gravity* is not able to write to the *out* topic, I am getting error message which is: `topic {out} doesn't have write credentials`

Also, the user *gravity* can subscribe to all the topics, not just *in*

Plus, I have another user, which is *william*, and *william* can subscribe to any topic, but can't publish on any topic. I don't know how it is possible that *william* can subscribe to any topic though the *acl* file states that I have just one user that has privilege listed

#### Note

I am adding a tag for mosquitto though I am working on moquette, and that is because they share the same acl format

#### Update

After readying the code of the broker,

I found that this is the function that is being called when a new subscription request comes:

```
@MQTTMessage(message = SubscribeMessage.class)
    void processSubscribe(ServerChannel session, SubscribeMessage msg) {
        String clientID = (String) session
                .getAttribute(NettyChannel.ATTR_KEY_CLIENTID);
        boolean cleanSession = (Boolean) session
                .getAttribute(NettyChannel.ATTR_KEY_CLEANSESSION);
        LOG.debug("SUBSCRIBE client <{}> packetID {}", clientID,
                msg.getMessageID());

        // ack the client
        SubAckMessage ackMessage = new SubAckMessage();
        ackMessage.setMessageID(msg.getMessageID());

        for (SubscribeMessage.Couple req : msg.subscriptions()) {
            AbstractMessage.QOSType qos = AbstractMessage.QOSType.values()[req
                    .getQos()];
            Subscription newSubscription = new Subscription(clientID,
                    req.getTopicFilter(), qos, cleanSession);
            boolean valid = subscribeSingleTopic(newSubscription,
                    req.getTopicFilter());
            ackMessage.addType(valid ? qos : AbstractMessage.QOSType.FAILURE);
        }
```

And I think that is the function that has a bug, because I can't see any call for IAuthorizator canRead function

I even tried to build my own plugin for authentication, and I have the exam same problem, which is authorization on publishing is working, but on subscribing it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you don't refer the right acl file, if it's in conf subdirectory remember the path has to be acl_file conf/acl.conf.

Regarding the read access, Moquette doesn't check the right on the subscription act, simply avoid to publish the mussages, but the deny is silent.

Andrea

Comment: Hi Andrea, I updated my question, could you check please

Comment: Hi man,

So sorry, it is working perfectly :)

And my plugin for authorization is working now

Appreciate it